# DrawIndexedInstanced with a different Index Count per Instance (Directx11)

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I have a lot of cases in my application, where I make drawcalls using the same shader with different uniform values and thought about instancing the drawcalls. However, the drawcalls have a varying number of triangles in my case.

As far as I understand `DrawIndexedInstanced`, it only permits to draw multiple instances with the same number of triangles/indices, so I guess I can't use this.

I thought that `DrawIndexedInstancedIndirect` may help, but that only seems to execute multiple calls to `DrawIndexedIstanced` basically.

Is there a way in Directx11 to draw instanced with a different number of triangles for each instance, or will I have to stay with normal drawcalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ff476410(v=vs.85).aspx), instanced drawing is to

> [...] reusing the same geometry to draw multiple objects in a scene.

It improves performance by not swapping the vertex data, but reusing it, which seems not be the case for your data, where the vertex sources are different for each draw call.

So you'll have to stick to single draw calls, but to improve your performance you could stage them after each other. Each state change has a certain cost being submitted to the gpu, if you keep your shader set as it is used for all draw calls, you can save some performance by doing all draw calls with the same shader and uniform values after each other and only switch if it is needed.